# Ramshackle GUI, using Absolute Positioning Randomly Turns Images Upsidedown

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, position

So, first of all I know Absolute Positioning isn't ideal for a GUI... However, I had to construct 4 different types of windows, and 1 overall game window, all with a built in runner. I had a day and a half to do this, and on a students schedule (especially one with no prior experience writing GUI's and a ban on JOptionPane), I did it fast and messy. With that out of the way here is the problem.

When running the GUI everything works as planned. However, on around 1/4 times running through the game a random image, will be flipped upside down. It's not always the same image, and doesn't occur every time. I having the image appear but painting directly on a JFrame (no panel, yes I know its bad programming). Thanks for any input you provide, couldn't really find anything online like this. Best advice I've found is when the same image is always upside down, but that's not the case.
Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;


public class game extends JFrame implements Runnable {

  private boolean running = false;
  private Image dbImage = null;
  private Dimension screenSize;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private int screenIndex = 0;
  private BufferedImage img = null;
  private dialog d = new dialog();
  private boolean a = false;
  private Room1 room1 = new Room1();
  private Room2 room2 = new Room2();
  private Room3 room3 = new Room3();
  private Room4 room4 = new Room4();
  private Room5 room5 = new Room5();
  private Room6 room6 = new Room6();
  private Toilet toilet = new Toilet();
  private final boolean UNLOCK = true;

  public game()
  {
    super("Game");
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon("pencil-icon.png").getImage());
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
    height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();

    (new Thread(this)).start();
  }

  public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    switch (screenIndex) {

      case 0:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("map.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6009.JPG"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        img = null;
        try{
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6010.JPG"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
        break;

      case 3:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6011.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6013.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 5:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5994.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;

      case 6:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5992.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 7:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5991.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
    }

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new game();
  }

  public void run() {
    running = true;

    while(running) {
      repaint();
      process();

      try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public int isScreenIndex() {
    return screenIndex;
  }
//SI 1 and 2 are working
  public void setScreenIndex(int s) {
    this.screenIndex = s;
  }
  public void process() {
    if (screenIndex==0)
    {
      try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
      catch (Exception e){}
      int a = -1;
      a = d.map();
      while (a==-1){
        try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (a==1 && ((room5.isDone() && !room1.isDone()) || UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(1);
        return;
      }
      if (a==2 && (!room2.isDone() || UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(2);
        return;
      }
      if (a==3 && (!room3.isDone() || UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(3);
        return;
      }
      if (a == 4 && ((!room4.isDone() && room3.isDone())||UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(4);
        return;
      }
      if (a == 5 && ((room4.isDone() && room6.isDone() && !room5.isDone())||UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(5);
        return;
      }
      if (a == 6 && ((room2.isDone() && !room6.isDone())||UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(6);
        return;
      }
      if (a == 7){
        d.showString("Progress",room1.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room1.getScore() + "\n" +
                     room2.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room2.getScore() + "\n" +
                     room3.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room3.getScore() + "\n" +
                     room4.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room4.getScore() + "\n" +
                     room5.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room5.getScore() + "\n" +
                     room6.getRoomName()  + "\t\t" + room6.getScore());
      }
      if (a == 8 && (!toilet.isDone() || UNLOCK)){
        setScreenIndex(7);
        return;
      }
    }
    if (screenIndex == 1){
      room1.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex == 2){
      room2.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex==3){
      //boolean a = false;
      room3.play();
      //while(!a){
      //  try {
      //    Thread.sleep(200);
      //  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      //  }
      //}
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex==4){
      room4.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex == 5){
      room5.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex == 6){
      room6.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
    if (screenIndex == 7){
      toilet.play();
      setScreenIndex(0);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"I don't think it will be useful to post my code..."` -- seriously? And we're supposed to guess why your program is strangely misbehaving how? Please look up [mcve].

Comment: And you've got a lot of admittedly bad programming going on. Why not fix it, since you know it's bad? Yes you shouldn't draw directly on a JFrame, so don't do it.

Comment: Well, I found a good way to lose reputation... main reason I said this is because I'm calling several files, approximately 9 other classes, and its 200 lines as is. I will post it immediately. I recognize I have bad programming going on, but the project is working besides this error, and I have 14 other students in the class working off this code. Any change in it can only be minor at this point, such as a bug fix.

Comment: Before posting, please again read the [mcve] link. You have posted your question too soon -- before doing work to try to isolate the problem, but also before trying to re-write your code so it does not use bad practices as well. There's a good chance that if you use only good practice, the bug will go away.

Comment: Added code. Sorry, I know the requirements, but I seriously didn't think it would be helpful for the stated reasons.

Comment: Please read, re-read, read again, study, do whatever it takes to understand the link given twice above, and once again here: [mcve].

Comment: You're asking for free advice from an all-volunteer site. It would be in your best interest to read the rules and regs of the site, best before asking, but since you can't do that now, at least do it now. It will improve your experience here greatly. Please start [here].

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding a JFrame's paint method here:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    switch (screenIndex) {

      case 0:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("map.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6009.JPG"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        img = null;
        try{
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6010.JPG"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
        break;

      case 3:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6011.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_6013.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 5:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5994.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;

      case 6:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5992.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
      case 7:
        img = null;
        try {
          img = ImageIO.read(new File("IMG_5991.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        break;
    }

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
  }
```

And doing several bad things inside of it:

- You shouldn't be painting in a JFrame since you risk messing the painting of the entire application including child components, borders, glasspane, contentPane, etc...
- You never call the super paint method -- probably your biggest bug
- You're actually reading a file from within this method, slowing it to a crawl. Never do file I/O from painting.
- You're ignoring exceptions with `catch (IOException e) {}`, a very dangerous practice and which is the coding equivalent of driving with your eyes closed.

Suggestions:

- First and foremost do what the tutorials tell you, what we have told countless folks who come here: **don't draw within a top level window**. Draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel.
- Do call the super painting method.
- Read the image in once, say in a constructor, store your images to variables, and never read them or do file i/o in a painting method.
- At least print the exception's stacktrace within your catch blocks.

Other issues:

- Your code is doing a lot of polling within a while loop suggesting that you want to change the program to be more "event-driven".
- Your code looks to be doing nothing but polling the states of other classes, and based on these results it changes an image displayed. If so, then much better would be:

  - Get rid of the polling and instead use an observer pattern to notify the image displaying class to change its image. This can be done using a PropertyChangeListener or a simple ChangeListener.
  - Again read all images once at program start up, and store them into variables. An ArrayList of Image or perhaps better, an `ArrayList<Icon>` would work well for this.
  - Display the images as ImageIcons in a JLabel
  - When the state change occurs, simply swap out images using JLabel's `setIcon(...)` method. This would make your program much more straightforward and bullet proof.

Something along the lines of...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// this is a JPanel and can be displayed in a JFrame
// a JDialog, or in another JPanel
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] IMG_PATHS = {
            "map.png",
            "IMG_6009.JPG",
            "IMG_6010.JPG",
            "IMG_6011.JPG",
            "IMG_6013.JPG",
            "IMG_5994.JPG",
            "IMG_5992.JPG",
            "IMG_5991.JPG"
    };
    private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    private List<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<>();
    private int iconIndex = 0;

    public GamePanel() {
        try {
            // read in the images once and only
            // once
            for (String imagePath : IMG_PATHS) {                
                // actually better to use resources
                // instead of Files here
                File file = new File(imagePath);
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
                Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                icons.add(icon);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // never ignore the exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageLabel.setIcon(icons.get(iconIndex));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // let outside classes easily change what image is displayed
    public void viewImage(int iconIndex) {
        if (iconIndex < 0 || iconIndex >= icons.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("iconIndex: " + iconIndex);
        } else {
            this.iconIndex = iconIndex;
            imageLabel.setIcon(icons.get(iconIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However, would any of these cause the for mentioned bug? I know it's bad practice but as I said previously, it works except for that issue. I'm not worried about reading a file inside the Paint method because it actually only runs very rarely. Only when moving to a new room. The super Paint method is a bug I hadn't noticed... and painting in the JFrame is fine because I never add any components to the JFrame, everything is done via pop ups through a separate class dialog which I programmed later and is working fine.

Comment: @R.Thom: no way of knowing without your posting a [mcve] that we can run, and not in a link.

Comment: I do not know what causes the problem however, that is the current problem. If I could identify what is causing it I would have it fixed. The only way I can think of creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example is if I were to give you copies of all the images I am using, and remove every single line of code from the game, then write a way for you to transition from image to image. If that is everything you need to answer the question than that by itself is an hour of work for something that may not even recreate a problem I have no idea as to the cause to.

Comment: @R.Thom: which is why creating a MCVE helps you *find* the problem. You cut out code til you isolate the problem, done.

Comment: Fair enough, I will delete this question and repost when I have done more myself.

Comment: @R.Thom: please see edit to answer. Why not simply swap ImageIcons in a JLabel. That would greatly simplify this code and solve your upside-down image problem in one fell swoop.

Comment: @R.Thom It's likely, as Hovercraft has pointed out, that you are getting paint artifacts from your improper use of the paint system